# Issue in accessing jacob-1.18-x86.dll at run time

Tags: java, maven, servlets, jacob, maven-dependency

Problem in resolving jacob-1.18-x86.dll , it cannot accessed at run time while 
i can successfully compile program.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jacob-1.14.3-x64 in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
        at com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:184)
        at com.jacob.com.JacobObject.<clinit>(JacobObject.java:108)
```

Maven dependency is :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
    <version>${jacob.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
    <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jacob</artifactId> 
    <version>1.14.3</version> 
    <classifier>x64</classifier> 
    <type>dll</type> 
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is `jacob-1.14.3-x64` actually in `java.library.path`?

Comment: tagged with "maven-dependency", formatted code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you put JACOB .dll files into your runtime library path?
E.g. in the folders:

> /Java/jdk/jre/bin

and

> /Java/jdk/jre/lib/ext/jacob-1.18

Comment: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\jre\bin

Comment: Yes i did that and checked still i am getting same error

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jacob-1.14.3-x64 in java.library.path
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
 at com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:184)
 at com.jacob.com.JacobObject.<clinit>(JacobObject.java:108)
 at com.jacob.com.LibraryLoader.loadJacobLibrary(LibraryLoader.java:181)
 at com.jacob.com.ComThread.<clinit>(ComThread.java:167)

Comment: Thank you very much. I was missing to add  jacob-1.14.3-x64.ddl and jacob-1.14.3-x84.dll both

Answer (score 1):

Now it is resolved when i added following files :

jacob-1.14.3-x64.ddl
and jacob-1.14.3-x84.dll

inside folders :

/Java/jdk/jre/bin
and 
/Java/jdk/jre/lib/ext

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve my problem by adding the `jacob-1.19-x64.dll` file in the first folder of `System.getProperty("java.library.path")`.

Just `system.out` the property and copy the `.dll` file in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's not always possible to add the dll to a folder from java.library.path. Hope this solution helps others.

Struggled with this a bit before I looked at the [source code for loading the dll](https://github.com/freemansoft/jacob-project/blob/14ba453c1c01eac9174cf33c6c998d5d090f35bc/jacob/src/com/jacob/com/LibraryLoader.java#L149). Add the below code before calling any methods from the Jacob library. This will instruct Jacob to load the dll from the specified path instead of looking in java.library.path.

`System.setProperty("jacob.dll.path", "/path/to/your/jacob/jacob-1.18-x86.dll");`

Works for version 1.20. But should work for older versions as well.